# Xamarin Forms Switch How To Remember & Update User Settings (Push Notifications)

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project / settings page that has a toggle / switch within Xamarin Forms. I am using xamarin essentials for storing user data, etc.

The goal is to have the switch / toggle save the position of the toggle when a user makes a change. And have this bound / binding to the app settings. I already have push notifications installed however I want to give the user the option to unsubscribe or to subscribe again.

Based on OneSignals documentation here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk#section--setsubscription-

This allows for the SetSubscription to be true or false. `OneSignal.SetSubscription(false);`

**This is my SettingsPage.xaml**

```
<Switch IsToggled="True"  Toggled="OnToggled" />
```

**This is my SettingsPage.xaml.cs**

```
void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {

            // Perform an action after examining e.Value

        }
```

My Goal is to have some app properties set and placed within the App.xaml.cs to be enabled on app launch and changed based on if the app contains the following keys to enable or disable notifications.

**This is my App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


             if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("PushDisabled"))
            {
                //Do things when push is disabled...
                OneSignal.SetSubscription(false);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("SetSubcription", false);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["PushDisabled"] = false;
                //Do things when push is enabled...
                OneSignal.SetSubscription(true);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("SetSubcription", true);
            }

            OneSignal.Current.StartInit("one-signal-key").EndInit();

        }
```

**Note**: OneSignal.SetSubscription(false); also causes this error: 'OneSignal' does not contain a definition for 'SetSubscription'.

Which is confusing, because it does reference it being here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk#section--setsubscription-

I need help creating the proper code to actually set the key when a user has disabled notifications and to set it back to enabled when a user has clicked to toggle / switch to active again.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated the StackOverflow community has been very helpful for me reviewing other questions however could to find anything on this topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OneSignal.Current.StartInit("app-id-code-here").EndInit();

if (!Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("PushDisabled"))
{
    //Prepare notification for first time.
    App.Current.Properties.Add("PushDisabled", false);
    App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

    Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("SetSubcription", true);

    OneSignal.Current.SetSubscription(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Xamarin Essentials for storing data. Try to store the toggled information in the Preferences and access it in your ViewModel to Bind to the UI. Refer to the below code.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("SetSubcription", true);
    OneSignal.SetSubscription(true);
}
```

Your view model must have a property accessing the value from the preferences.

```
public bool IsToggledValue
{
    get { return Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("SetSubcription", false); }
}
```

Then you can bind the property from the ViewModel to your View in whichever page you are using it.

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsToggledValue}"  Toggled="OnToggled" />
```

Please note that the BindingContext for your Switch must be ViewModel to get this logic working.

In your OnToggled callback, you can decide whether to subscribe to the push notifications or not.

```
private void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Value)
    {
        OneSignal.SetSubscription(true);
    }
    else
    {
        OneSignal.SetSubscription(false);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Please let me know you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However I noticed that "PushDisabled" does not have any function. Should I remove this or this will be set after adding the bool reference?

Comment: I have tried your code set, however it did not seem to do anything. After the app is closed out the toggle goes back to its original state after the user has made a change. It should be default set, then if a user disables it then should reference that user has unsubed from push and also keep the toggle position.

Comment: Also checked if it would prevent a user from receiving a notification and it did not... I believe this needs to be configured within the void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) function.

Comment: I am not sure of the requirement of PushDisabled. I just left it as you might use it for any other purpose. If that is not required then yes, you can remove it.

Comment: I have modified the answer to initially set the toggled enabled and subscribe to push notification. Whenever you interact with your switch now the subscription can be changed. 

I have just directly called the method OneSignal in the event callback. Not sure if its public static or not. However, you can always edit the answer based on your requirements to point to a correct reference of an object to call the method.

Comment: @Harikrishnan yes,you should update the value when toggle the switch

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT: It is already done in the updated answer. Have called the OneSignal.SetSubscription method based on the toggle value.

Comment: OneSignal.SetSubscription(true); apparently does not work. Are you on upwork? I created a job if you want to maybe do that?

https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~01ca1d51fc6e7e4959

Comment: @ODApplications contact me through upwork i will help you ,you sent invitation to me but i need more details

Comment: Sure @OD Applications. I will look into this.